# Using jQuery to cache DOM elements

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with naming conventions, and I'd like to come up with a convention for any variables that are cache variables for DOM elements.

So far, I've progressed to using this:

```
window.x = $('#x');
```

Now of course, that puts it into the global scope, but according to my convention, that's ok.

But the problem with that is that looking at window.x doesn't convey to me that it's a cache variable of $('#x').  So now what I'd like to experiment with is using a jQuery plugin technique to store these values.  Something like:

```
;(function($, window, undefined) {
    $.fn.x = function() {
        return $('#x');
    }
})(jQuery, window);
```

That way, I can reference $x.val() and it will immediately convey to me that $x is a cache of the $('#x') DOM element.

Q: How would I create a plugin called x that is the return value of the $('#x') selector?
Am I doing it right?  Now, you might say (in your best Office Space voice over) "This is a horrible idea", but I'm just experimenting.

Comment: Oh, I don't know if it's a horrible idea. But I have an easier one-- I just put a dollar sign at the beginning of otherwise normal variables (I do use the $ as an alias for jQuery as well): `$this = $(this)` or `$widget = $('#widget')`

Comment: scope your variables local to your function, don't keep them in global scope. if they're jQuery collections, prefix the variable name with a `$`. This whole caching nonsense **is** a terrible idea. Caching is used to improve performance, but as JavaScript is run asynchronously, 99% of the time performance isn't an issue because you'll spend so much time idling.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a reason to cache DOM elements. For starters, if you are using jQuery id selectors, those are the fastest type of selectors, so there is no need to cache DOM elements. When you are adding to your global namespace in your example, you are merely creating a shortcut or alias for selecting the element with the id of "x". In my code, I use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to encapsulate a single scoped part of my code. I place global variables at the beginning if they are going to be referenced repeatedly. Here's an example:

```
// An immediately-invoked function expression wraps all JavaScript code to keep it scoped to this module.
(function ($) {
    // Closure-local variables.
    var $grid;
    var $table;
    // etc.

    // Bind an initialize event. Will be called when this code needs to execute.
    $(document).on('initialize', initialize);

    // Initialize the global variables.
    function initialize() {     
        $grid = $('#grid');
        $table = $('#table');

        // other setup...
    }

})(jQuery);
```

I use an initialize event that get triggered when the page initially loads, which sets the global variables and sets up the IIFE. The IIFE keeps your code seperate from all other code and the "cached" elements are merely global variables set up in the initialize event so you don't have to call them repeatedly.